# rails 3, active record: any way to tell how many unique values match a "x LIKE ?" query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-like

I have a query to find all the phone numbers that match a partial expression such as "ends with 234"

```
@matchingphones = Calls.find :all, 
    :conditions => [ "(thephonenumber LIKE ?)", "%234"]
```

The same phone number might be in the database several times, and so might be returned multiple times by this query if it matches.

What I need is to know is UNIQUE phone numbers the query returns.

For example if the database contains

```
000-111-1234 *
000-111-3333
000-111-2234 *
000-111-1234 *
000-111-4444
```

the existing query will return the 3 records marked with * (eg returns one phone number -1234 twice since it's in the database twice)

what I  need is a query that returns just once instance of each match, in this case

```
000-111-1234 *
000-111-2234 *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Calls.find :all, 
    :select => "id, DISTINCT thephonenumber",
    :conditions => [ "(thephonenumber LIKE ?)", "%234"]
```

In addition,
1. You are using rails 2 query syntax.. better switch to rails 3 (arel)
2. Better name your class Call (not Calls)

Answer (score 0):

```
Call.where("thephonenumber LIKE ?", "%234").group(:thephonenumber)
```

if you just want the count then you can do:

```
Call.where("thephonenumber LIKE ?", "%234").group(:thephonenumber).all.count
```